# Problem in New Stack UI Change

Tags: discussion, support, new-nav

When I click My favourite tags in `php` it loads the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/php?show=all&sort=newest` and its work fine.

But if I use Browser back button it will load some thing like this(As previous page).

[image]

You can **check arrow mark** and **time** I marked in the image.

But if I click that link, it is very **older one**(check below image)

[image: Image 2]

**Note:** this happening me all the time(today more than 10+, yesterday too), once it can be show because of **page is not refreshed**. But its showing me each and every time??

any idea??

Comment: Me too, I just got `show=all&sort=newest&tagFilter=all` full of questions 24 hours old